# Jasmine and Karma: Cannot find variable runs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Do I need a plugin/lib to use runs() and waits() with Jasmine?  I'm looking at the Jasmine wiki page for async tests: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs.

They have no mention of needing a special lib/plugin, so I assume runs() and waits() should work out of the box.

My code looks like this (it's wrapped in a describe):

```
it('test', function() {
    runs(function() {

    });
});
```

I'm getting: `ReferenceError: runs is not defined`

The relevant portion of my karma config is:

```
    files: [
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/*.js',
        'test/*.spec.js'
    ],


    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins: [
        'karma-spec-reporter',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically if you want to run an async test, you should use the [$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/%24httpBackend) service, which when flushed will trigger the right events and your tests will run smoothly.

EDIT:
Each of the angularjs timed actions are wrapped in promises and digest cycles. In the case of `$timeout` to trigger the digest cycle that triggers it you can do `$timeout.flush()`.

For example you can have:

```
expect($scope.timedvariable).toEqual('before timeout value');
// Flush the timeout service
$timeout.flush();
// the actions within the $timeout are executed
expect($scope.timedvariable).toEqual('value after timeout');
```

Comment: Ah, ok, but I am not using `'ng-scenario'` in my `frameworks:['jasmine']`?  Also, I am just trying to test a directive that adds a class to an element, and then after a $timeout, removes the class.  So I don't think I need $httpBackend for that, but rather runs() and waits().

Comment: @user2736286 I edited my post correcting it with the right kind of information and adding you a about how to flush a timeout in angularjs correctly.

Comment: This, while helpful, does not answer the question that was asked. It should also address the question that was asked: why Jasmine can't find ```runs```.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, so it turns out Jasmine 2.0 has removed `runs()`, `waits()` and `waitsFor()`.  The new async support uses `done()`, which be found at: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support.  I've added a quick note to the outdated github wiki page about this.